# HTML Table not updating after submitting form (updates after additional refresh of page)

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, wordpress

**

### Background

**
I am using wordpress to build a website. On my wordpress page, I am running a PHP snippet, which essentially allows me to run a PHP script on my page.

In this PHP Script, I make a POST to an API which contains the logged in user's username. This username is the unique identifier so that the API can return a response with the record for that username from the database.

Once the API returns a response (as JSON), I display that data in an HTML table.

In order to edit records in the API's database, I submit an HTML form. This HTML form is seperate from the PHP script. To be clear, the HTML form is used to edit the database. The PHP script simply makes a POST to query the database and returns the response in an HTML table above the HTML form.

**

### Question

**

When I submit the form, the page refreshes (I think), but I don't see updated data in my HTML table. However, if I refresh the page once, then I do see the updated data in the HTML table. This means that the form submission is being successfully received by the API, the API is successfully updating the database, the API is successfully returning the data from the database -- however, it requires that I refresh the page after submitting the form.

How can I make it so that after submitting the form, the updated data automatically appears in the HTML table without an additional refresh?

### **What I've Tried**

One thing I've already tried is manually refreshing the page after submitting the form, so the user doesn't have to refresh the page themselves. I've tried using code like location.reload(); and calling this in window.onload = function()

However, this didn't work and also manually forcing another refresh after form submit just didn't seem like best practice to me.

I also didn't want to keep pinging the API every few seconds asynchronously and strain the server.

**

### Goal

**

My ideal end result is that after submitting the form, the change is immediately reflected in the HTML table without an additional refresh.

Comment: please add some code by that i can give you a solution

Comment: You can do it simpler:
1. Use AJAX, its builtin WordPress.
2. Use is-user-looged-in() to get all personal data

So from Ajax call you will be able to update data base
and from the callback you will update the page online.

Exactly what you want